# ASP.NET HTML get selected radio button and use it on a link

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, radio-button

I'm on a project using ASP.NET MVC5 with Razor.

I have a table in a `View` that it regroups some information who compose an historic.
This historic is on many year and I don't want the user seen all year when user go on this page, it's so many information in the same time. So I develop a system where the user can select year of his choice, and he can select all years.

But this system doesn't work...

I have a dynamic list of radio buttons:

```
foreach (var item in @ViewBag.annees)
{
    if (@item == @ViewBag.selectAnnee)
    {
         <label class="reset-this" for="@i">
        <input id="@i" type="radio" name="annee" value="@item" checked="checked">
          @item
          </label>
     }
     else
     {
          <label class="reset-this" for="@i">
          <input id="@i" type="radio" name="annee" value="@item ">
          @item
          </label>
      }
      i++;
 }
      if (@ViewBag.selectAnnee == 0)
      {
          <label class="reset-this" for="0">
          <input id="0" type="radio" name="annee" value="0" checked="checked">
          Toutes les années
          </label>
       }
       else
       {
           <label class="reset-this" for="0">
           <input id="0" type="radio" name="annee" value="0">
           Toutes les années
           </label>
       }
```

The zero is for all years.

I want to add a link that call the good method like this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Historique formateur", "../Histo/IndexHistoFormateur", 
                 new {  id = Model.sId, annee = @dateEnCour  })
```

But I don't know how get the value of the selected radio button to put in my link.

Comment: The question is not so clear. where you are declaring your ActionLink? out side the loop or inside? or else you want to do some post operations. what's the requirement? can you eloborate little so that it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I’m sorry for the late reply. My ActionLink  are declaring after my first piece of code...